# Is it possible to change route on scroll?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I want to load multiple components on a single page and have different routes for all of them. For example i hit a route /article/1 and it loads a component, after scrolling through completely through that article i want the route to change to /article/2 and the corresponding article to load. I am using react and react router, basically i want 4 (article/3 , article/4) articles on a page and all these should be scrollable with the route changing as i scroll onto a particular article. How can i achieve this using react and react-router?

Comment: You can use react-infinite-scroll-component npm package and load it on demand .

Answer (score 2):

use `react-perfect-scrollbar` package from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar).

> index.js (main entry point of your application) add this css

```
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
```

> your component file where you want on scroll change url

```
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';

import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

handleScroll = () => {
  <Redirect to="/article/2" />
} 

<PerfectScrollbar onYReachEnd={this.handleScroll}> // when you reach then end of screen it's call handleScroll function and redirect to other url.so based on your requirements you can pick up from here. 
    // your articles code..
</PerfectScrollbar>
```