# How do i change to another page on scroll with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a design with a landing page with 100vh and 100vw. upon scrolling down its supposed to load in another page.
How can i go about this with react hooks and react router?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone provided some options in a similar question. Namely, `react-perfect-scrollbar` from npm.

[Is it possible to change route on scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512817/is-it-possible-to-change-route-on-scroll)

Just sharing it here for you.